# How do i consolidate a bunch of projects from one git repo into a single folder In Eclipse Project viewer?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

Working on a project in Eclipse for OpenDaylight OVSDB with a bunch of sub projects in the repo for it. I want to be able to easily refresh all the projects with a single refresh when i do a git pull so i can see new projects that show up. All these projects are Maven / Java projects and i'm not sure how i can easily just refresh them as they are one long list of projects all from this repo that connect together. here is a screenshot of what i'm talking about.

[image: Image of Eclipse Package Explorer]

And here is the example of what I want it to look like.

[image]

Notice how there is a top folder for all of them that i can easily just right click on and refresh and it updates all the projects under the top level repo.

Answer (score 1):

Change to working set view. Add a working set to contain all of these projects. Right-click on working set and select refresh.